# Given a path go to the sub folders and make a list of all Excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Given a File Path.
I am trying to import all the (xlsx) files that start with '001-'100 within that folder (So far I am able to import them with the following macro)

```
Sub Select_Folder()
    'returns a list of files located in the indicated folder

    Dim directory As String
    Dim firstFile As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    ''Dim bottom As String
    Dim IB As String
    Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

    'checks to see if Filter Mode is on.
    'Prompts the user to turn off filter mode
    'and aborts the function

    If Sheets("Master").FilterMode = True Then
        MsgBox "The Macro was aborted for the following reason:" & vbNewLine & _
        "The Filter on this sheet is still active." & vbNewLine & _
        "Please turn off FilterMode off to continue. (Error: 002)", vbCritical + vbApplicationModal, "Microsoft Excel"
        End
    End If

    'Turn Off Screen Updating and
    'Event Handiling
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With



    Sheets("Master").Range("C4", Range("C4").End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Delete

    'the directory is taken from the inputs on the spreadsheet 

    Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With diaFolder
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\"
        On Error GoTo Err2:
        .Show
        directory = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    Set diaFolder = Nothing

    If Len(Dir(directory, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The Macro was aborted for the following reason:" & vbNewLine & _
        "The directory " & directory & " Does not exist." & vbNewLine & _
        "Please check to make sure that this directory exists. (Error: 005)", vbCritical + vbApplicationModal, "No Directory Exists"
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        End
    End If

    'sets the first file in the folder
    'if no first file exists, the program ends

    firstFile = Dir(directory)

    If firstFile = "" Then
        MsgBox "The Macro was aborted for the following reason:" & vbNewLine & _
        "There are no files in the directory: " & directory & vbNewLine & _
        "Please check to make sure that there are files in this Directory. (Error: 006)", vbCritical + vbApplicationModal, "No Files Exist"
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        End
    End If

    'places the first file in the first row

    Range("B4") = -1
    Range("D4") = firstFile
    Range("C4") = Left(firstFile, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(" ", firstFile) - 1)
    Range("D2") = directory

    'finds the next files in the folder
    'Looks at the first four characters in the file name
    'if the first four characters returned.

    Do
        dataFile = Dir()
        If dataFile = "" Then
            Exit Do
        ElseIf Left(dataFile, 4) <> "Term" And Left(dataFile, 4) <> "Inac" Then
            Range("D4").Select
            'finds the next blank cell in range "D5"
'            Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
            Do Until ActiveCell.Text = ""
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
            Loop

            ActiveCell.Value = dataFile
            IB = Left(dataFile, Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(" ", dataFile) - 1)
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = IB
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = -1
        End If
    Loop

    'finds the lowest cell in the range to set as the base
    'fills two formulas to find the Name and Type of Report starting at E4 and F4
    'Autofits Columns E and F
Err2:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Now I want to be able to not only do it for that folder but also the folders inside (Sub Folders).

I tried implementing

```
Sub DoFolderFolder_backup()
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        ' Operate on each file
    Call Select_Folder
    Next
```

Please help me.

The format of the "Master sheet" is the following

[image]

Comment: [This may be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827715/get-list-of-sub-directories-in-vba)

Comment: You should probably be recording the subfolder path that can be appended to `c:\Users` to uniquely identify each file. btw, the term to describe a search for all subfolders within a folder is **recursive**.

Comment: (I will be selecting the folder path that goes into D2 with the first Macro) 
So should I consider having another column that has each (recursive) file's unique file path?